# Minishift - How to edit files of a project deployed from bitbucket repository

Tags: laravel, openshift-origin, minishift

I have setup Minishift on my computer and installed a custom laravel from a github repo on minishift using the web console.

How do I access the downloaded files locally and test my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using cwRsync client. As per the official documentation given below:

https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/copy_files_to_container.html